# Find all roots of the equation $2x^3+x^2+75x-81=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, radicals, substitution, cubics

Find all roots of the equation
$$2x^3+x^2+75x-81=0$$

Please check my work,

Let $P(x)$ : $2x^3+x^2+75x-81=0$

$ 2\left(x-\frac{1}{6}\right)^3 + \left(x-\frac{1}{6}\right)^2 + 75\left(x-\frac{1}{6}\right)-81 = 0$

$2x^3 + \frac{1}{6}x - \frac{1}{3}x +75x-\frac{1}{108}+\frac{1}{36}- \frac{75}{6}-81 = 0$

$2x^3 + 74\frac{5}{6}x - 93\frac{13}{27}=0$

$x^3 + 37\frac{5}{12}x - 46\frac{20}{27}=x^3+px+q = 0$

Let $u, v \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u+v$ be the real root of the equation.

By Cardano method,

$u^3v^3 = \frac{-\left(37\frac{5}{12}\right)^3}{27} = -\frac{p^3}{27}u^3+v^3 = 46\frac{20}{27} = -q$

$p=37\frac{5}{12}, q= -46\frac{20}{27}$

$\{u^3, v^3\}= \left\{\frac{-q}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{q^2+\frac{4p^3}{27}}, \frac{-q}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{q^2+\frac{4p^3}{27}}\right\}$

choose $u, v$ for which $uv = -\frac{p}{3}$

$\{u, v\}= \left\{\sqrt[3]{\frac{-q}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{q^2+\frac{4p^3}{27}}}, \sqrt[3]{\frac{-q}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt[3]{q^2+\frac{4p^3}{27}}}\right\}$

Thus, roots of the equation are

$u+v-\frac{1}{6}, u\omega^2+v\omega-\frac{1}{6},u\omega+v\omega^2-\frac{1}{6} $ , where $\omega = cis\frac{2\pi}{3}$

Comment: you will Need this here https://math.vanderbilt.edu/schectex/courses/cubic/

Comment: The basic techniques don't work well here and it has complex roots, so my guess is that you need to use the full formula for the roots.

Comment: Is it maybe $2x^3+3x^2+75x-81=0$ or $2x^3+x^2+78x-81=0$?

Comment: I am just putting forward an idea. I know my method would be very complex but you can try making realtions with roots such as- (alpha×beta×gamma)= (-d/a). Simmilary get relations for (alpha+ beta+ gamma) and also for (aplha×beta + beta×gamma + gamma×apha). Now you have 3 equations and 3 variables and now just solve.

Answer (score 4):

$$2x^3+x^2+75x-81=2\left(x^3+\frac{1}{2}x^2+\frac{75}{2}x-\frac{81}{2}\right)=$$
$$=2\left(x^3+3\cdot\frac{1}{6}x^2+3\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^2x+\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^3+\left(\frac{75}{2}-\frac{1}{12}\right)x-\frac{1}{216}-\frac{81}{2}\right)=$$
$$=2\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{6}\right)^3+\frac{449}{12}x-\frac{8749}{216}\right)=$$
$$=2\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{6}\right)^3+\frac{449}{12}\left(x+\frac{1}{6}\right)-\frac{449}{72}-\frac{8749}{216}\right)=$$
$$=2\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{6}\right)^3+\frac{449}{12}\left(x+\frac{1}{6}\right)-\frac{1262}{27}\right).$$
Thus, we need to solve the following equation
$$y^3+py+q=0,$$
where $y=x+\frac{1}{6}$, $p=\frac{449}{12}$ and $q=-\frac{1262}{27}$.

It's obvious that our equation has unique real root

because for example $$\left(\left(x+\frac{1}{6}\right)^3+\frac{449}{12}\left(x+\frac{1}{6}\right)\right)'=3\left(x+\frac{1}{6}\right)^2+\frac{449}{12}>0.$$
Let $y=u+v$ is a root of the equation $y^3+py+q=0$.

Hence, $$u^3+v^3+3uv(u+v)+p(u+v)+q=0$$ or
$$u^3+v^3+q+(u+v)(3uv+p)=0.$$
Let $uv=-\frac{p}{3}$.

Hence, $u^3+v^3=-q$, which says that $u^3$ and $v^3$ are roots of the equation
$$z^2+qz-\frac{p^3}{27}=0$$ or
$$z^2-\frac{1262}{27}z-\frac{1}{27}\left(\frac{449}{12}\right)^3=0,$$
which gives
$$x=-\frac{1}{6}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{631}{27}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{631}{27}\right)^2+\frac{1}{27}\left(\frac{449}{12}\right)^3}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{631}{27}-\sqrt{\left(\frac{631}{27}\right)^2+\frac{1}{27}\left(\frac{449}{12}\right)^3}}$$

Comment: @amWhy I think it would better if I'll write a full solution. What do you think?

Comment: Sure, if you'd like to!  I'd be willing to upvote your answer if it's written well to address the level of the asker.  And even if it's at any level, since the asker hasn't made clear his/her needs, level of study, etc.

Comment: Nice work, @Michael